# Text labels on axis

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to make a chart in Libreoffice Calc 4.2.8.2.
I want the X axis to be built according to a time column but to show text labels from a different one. The columns look as follow:

```
               Input Output
First   00:01    23    45
Second  00:02    45    67
Third   00:20    23    18
Fourth  00:50    8     40
```

Using only the last 3 columns I get a chart with x-axis distributed according to column 2 and with column 2 values as labels.
I would like to mantain the X-axis interval distribution but changing labels in the axis for the text labels in the first column. It would be something like what you can do in gnuplot with xtic command.
Is that possible in Calc?

I am using the XY (scatter) chart. I get a chart with labels in the axis that do not correspond to values in column 2 but to equally spaced values. I would like the axis to show only the values I provide in the column. Is that possible? I could do so with a line chart but then the values would not be spaced according to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to space the axis by times and also change the axis labels.  What you can do is add labels to the individual data points:

- Make sure the label column is included in the data range: In the data ranges window, on the tab "Data Series" make sure the label column is selected in the field "data labels" for each series
- Select the data series
- Right-click and choose "insert data labels" (the numbers will appear)
- Right-click and choose "format data labels"
- On the tab "data labels" uncheck the box "show value as number" (to remove the numbers) and check the box "show category" (to add "first", "second", etc.)
- By default the label will be displayed above the data point, you can change this to below or right/left

Hopefully that will get the functionality you are looking for.

**Edit**
Another possible workaround is to space out the data points with blank rows so they are charted with the correct spacing.  In some cases this spacing can be done with formulas.  Though the exact formulas don't apply in this case, maybe the file example attached to this forum post can be a starting off point: [Plot multiple series with different number of values](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=67912&p=302586#p302708)

Note that when there are blank lines in the data source, you'll need to set an option for each data series to get the data points connected.  After selecting a data series, right-click and choose "Format Data Series".  In the pop up window on the tab "Options", under "Plot Options" for "Plot missing values" select the radio button "Continue line".

Comment: In the real chart i want to build I have more columns to be drawn than those input and output ones I have inclued in the example. Therefore, it is not as clear to include data labels in one of them than to show labels in the axis. I have modified my question to include another option that may be useful.

Comment: Another workaround option would be to space out the data points - add blank rows so the points space correctly on a line chart.  The spacing can be done with formulas.  There's an example that might get you started in this forum post: [Re: Plot multiple series with different number of values](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=67912&p=302586#p302708); although that would need some heavy modification to work for your data set.

Comment: Thanks! That is useful, I have managed to space correctly my axis. However, spacing does not work fine with data. Data separated by blank row appears in separated points, instead of connected with a line. I can use interpolated values in those blank rows but I would rather not use more data points.

Comment: I'm glad the axis is working for you.  To get the datapoints connected, select each data series then right-click and choose "Format Data Series" and on the tab "Options" under "Plot Options" for "Plot missing values" select the radio button "Continue line".

Comment: Thanks! That is what i wanted. Please update your answer with the spacing workaround and I will accept it.